# Recursion value default change

Tags: python, recursion, default

I want to make sure 'rep' isn't made 0 at the beginning of each recursion. At the current point it is defaulted to starting at 0, but I want it to save the value of rep+=1.

Is there an easy fix?

```
def printPattern(n,k,rep =0):
    'prints a pattern of stars'
    if n == k:
        print ('{}{}'.format(' '*rep,'*'*n))
    elif n%2 == 0:
        rep+=1
        print ('{}{}'.format(' '*rep,'*'*n))
        printPattern(n+1,k)
    else:
        rep+=1
        print ('{}*'.format(' '*rep))
        printPattern(n+1,k)
```

Comment: Pass your rep to recursive function call..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by actually passing rep in your recursive call

```
printPattern(n+1,k, rep)
```

```
def printPattern(n,k,rep =0):
    'prints a pattern of stars'
    if n == k:
        print ('{}{}'.format(' '*rep,'*'*n))
    elif n%2 == 0:
        rep+=1
        print ('{}{}'.format(' '*rep,'*'*n))
        printPattern(n+1,k, rep)
    else:
        rep+=1
        print ('{}*'.format(' '*rep))
        printPattern(n+1,k, rep)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    rep+=1
    print ('{}{}'.format(' '*rep,'*'*n))
    printPattern(n+1,k, rep)
```

If you pass new value of `rep` as 3rd parameter, then default value 0 will not be used.

So, when you call this function the first time, you can actually skip using the 3rd parameter, then the default value will be used. But the next time, every recursive call to this function will take `rep` as 3rd parameter, passed as the current value of `rep`